# Can't call openDrawer() in DrawerLayoutAndroid, react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, jsx

I'm a newbie in react-native. What I try to do is putting a drawer on the screen and open it with the "menu" button in the toolbar.
I know that I must use callback functions, I previously searched a lot of topics and related questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248593/how-do-i-call-the-opendrawer-function-on-drawerlayoutandroid-from-parent-compone) but I couldn't do it. Getting Almost crazy. Here's my code:

```js
/**
 * @flow
 */

const React = require('react');
const ReactNative = require('react-native');

const { View, Text, DrawerLayoutAndroid } = ReactNative;


class Profile extends React.Component<{}> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
    headerRight: <Text>Menu</Text>,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);
  }
  openDrawer() {
    this.ref.drawer.openDrawer();
  }

  render() {
    const navigationView = (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left' }}>Im in the Drawer!</Text>
      </View>
    );
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
        ref={(_drawer) => {
          this.drawer = _drawer;
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right' }}>Hello</Text>
          <Text
            style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right' }}
            onPress={this.openDrawer()}
          >
            World!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Every time I run the code, I get the "undefined is not an object".

Also, I don't know how to put `openDrawer()` inside the `static navigationOptions`.

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: `onPress={this.openDrawer()}` should be `onPress={this.openDrawer}`

Comment: Wow! That actually solved my problem partially. Thank you @bennygenel
I also corrected `this.ref.drawer.openDrawer();` to `this.drawer.openDrawer();`